# Как соединить QLineEdit и кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton, qlineedit

Я делаю программу с интерфейсом в *Qt Designer* для вычисления длины окружности и площади круга.

Как соединить `QLineEdit` и `QPushButton`?

Код интерфейса:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 339)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.dlina = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.dlina.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 230, 151, 51))
        self.dlina.setObjectName("dlina")
        self.ploshad = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ploshad.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 151, 51))
        self.ploshad.setObjectName("ploshad")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 100, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.radius = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.radius.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 191, 41))
        self.radius.setText("")
        self.radius.setObjectName("radius")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислитель"))
        self.dlina.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Длина окружности"))
        self.ploshad.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Площадь круга"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите радиус"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**main.py**:

```
import math
print("Что вы хотите найти?")
print("Площадь круга - 1")
print("Длину окружности - 2 ") 
chto=int(input())
if chto==1 :
    r=float(input("Введите радиус r ="))
    s=math.pi*(r**2)
    print("Площадь круга равна : ", s)
elif chto==2 :
    r=float(input("Введите радиус r ="))
    p=2*math.pi*r
    print("Длина окружности равна : ", p)
else :
    print("Ты помоему чето перепутал")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Спросите если что-то не понятно.

```
import sys
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 339)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.dlina = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.dlina.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 230, 151, 51))
        self.dlina.setObjectName("dlina")
        self.ploshad = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ploshad.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 151, 51))
        self.ploshad.setObjectName("ploshad")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 100, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.radius = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.radius.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 191, 41))
        self.radius.setText("")
        self.radius.setObjectName("radius")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислитель"))
        self.dlina.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Длина окружности"))
        self.ploshad.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Площадь круга"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите радиус"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.dlina.clicked.connect(lambda: self.calculation('dlina'))
        self.ploshad.clicked.connect(lambda: self.calculation('ploshad'))
        
        
    def calculation(self, value):
        r = self.radius.text()
        if not r:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Введите радиус.')
            return

        if value == 'dlina':
            p = 2 * math.pi * float(r)
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Успех', 
                f"Длина окружности равна: {p:.3f}")
        elif value == 'ploshad':
            s = math.pi * (float(r) ** 2)
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Успех', 
                f"Площадь круга равна: {s:.3f}")
                
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное